# How to have a table appear on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm coding this price calculator and I want to have a table to appear with a tiered pricing when hovering over "info". This is the tiered pricing:

```
var pricingbackendzr = {4:35,10:32.5,20:30};
var pricingbackendz = {4:20,10:18,20:16};
var pricingapp = {10:7.5,25:7,50:6.5,75:6,1000:5.5};
```

I tried putting it in a table but when i hovered over it nothing would appear.

```js
//diese funktion wird ausgelöst wenn das html-dokument vollstaendig geladen wird
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var updatecolor = document.querySelectorAll('.updatecolor');

  document.querySelectorAll(".updatecolor").forEach(updateinputs =>
    updateinputs.addEventListener("input", function (){
      var percent = calcPercent(this.value,this.min,this.max);
      const bg = getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('--background');
      const slider = getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('--slider');
      var colorchanger = this.getAttribute('rangecolorid');
      var sliderselect = document.querySelector('#'+colorchanger);
      sliderselect.setAttribute(
           'style',
               ` background:linear-gradient(to right,${slider},${slider} ${percent}%,${bg} ${percent}%) `
      )
    })
  );

});


//funktion damit der Slider sich beim eingeben vom input field bewegt
function updateUser(val, inputtype) {
  if (inputtype == 'Appuserrangecolor') {
    document.getElementById('AppInput').value = val;
  }
  if (inputtype == 'AppInput') {
    document.getElementById('Appuserrangecolor').value = val;
  }
  if (inputtype == 'Backendrangecolor') {
    document.getElementById('BackendInput').value = val;
  }
  if (inputtype == 'BackendInput') {
    document.getElementById('Backendrangecolor').value = val;
  }
  calcSum();
}

//Calculates the percentage of the currentval with the base of a min and max value
function calcPercent(curval, min, max){
  return ((curval - min) / (max - min))*100;
}


//Rechnung für die Anzahl von Backend und App-Benutzern
function calcSum() {
  var preisproapp = document.querySelector('.proapp');
  var backendpreissum = document.querySelector('.backendpreissum');
  var appstk = document.querySelector('.appanzahl');
  var preisprobackend = document.querySelector('.probackend');
  var jaehrlich = document.querySelector('.jaehrlichsum');
  var summetext = document.querySelector('.summe');
  var rabatt = document.querySelector('.rabattsum');
  var backendanzahl = document.querySelector(".backenduser").value;
  var appanzahl = document.querySelector(".appuser").value;
  var paymenttype = document.querySelector("#zahlrythmus").value;
  var backendtype = document.querySelector("#backendfunktion").value;

  var percent = 1; //Standardvalue for yearly

  if(paymenttype == "M"){
    percent = 1.2; //standardvalue for monthly
  }
  //Preisstaffelung für app und backend
  apppreis = 7.5;
  backendpreis = 35;
  //Preisstaffelung Zeiterfassung+Rechnungswesen für Backendpreis
  var pricingbackendzr = {4:35,10:32.5,20:30};
  var pricingbackendz = {4:20,10:18,20:16};
  var pricingapp = {10:7.5,25:7,50:6.5,75:6,1000:5.5};

  if(backendtype == "ZR"){
    backendpreis = getPrice(pricingbackendzr, percent, backendanzahl);
  }else{
    backendpreis = getPrice(pricingbackendz, percent, backendanzahl);
  }

  apppreis = getPrice(pricingapp, percent, appanzahl);

  //Rechnungen für gesamtsumme
  var mytext = (((backendanzahl * backendpreis + +appanzahl * apppreis) * 1)).toFixed(2);
  summetext.textContent = mytext+"€";
  //Rechnung für Backendpreissumme
  var backendpreissumme = (backendanzahl * backendpreis).toFixed(2);
  backendpreissum.textContent = backendpreissumme+"€";
  //Rechnung für Apppreissumme
  var apppreissumme = (appanzahl * apppreis).toFixed(2);
  appstk.textContent = apppreissumme+"€";
  //Rechnung für Preis pro Backendbenutzer
  var probackend2 = ((backendpreis * backendanzahl) / (backendanzahl)).toFixed(2);
  preisprobackend.textContent = probackend2;
  //Rechnung für Preis pro App-Benutzer
  var proapp2 = appanzahl > 0 ? ((apppreis * appanzahl) / (appanzahl)).toFixed(2) : apppreis.toFixed(2);
  preisproapp.textContent = proapp2;
  //If Abfrage wenn "Jaehrlich" ausgewaehlt wird
  if(paymenttype == "J"){
    var jaehrlicherrabatt = ((backendanzahl * backendpreis + +appanzahl * apppreis)*12).toFixed(2);
    jaehrlich.textContent = jaehrlicherrabatt+"€";
  }
  //Rechnung für Ersparnis
  var rabattsum = (jaehrlicherrabatt * 0.2).toFixed(2);
  rabatt.textContent = "-"+rabattsum+"€"+" (20%)";
}

//Rechnung für Jaehrlich und Monatlich(10% Rabatt für Jaehrlich)
function checkHide(element){
  var hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenMonthly');
  if (element && hidden) {
    element.value === 'M' ? (hidden.style.visibility = 'hidden')  : (hidden.style.visibility = 'unset')
  }
}

function getPrice(pricemodels, percent, amount){
  for ( var key in pricemodels ) {
    //If key is higher than the selected amount, return the value
    if(parseInt(key) >= parseInt(amount)){
      return pricemodels[key] * percent;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

* {
  font:13px/20px PTSansRegular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

input[type=range]{
  border-radius: 32px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:600px 250px ;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.grid-item-1 {
  align-self: start;
  justify-self: center;
}


/* Background Styles Only */

/*@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');*/



.text-grey{
  color:grey;
}


.grid-container {
  padding: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 200px;
}

#Backendrangecolor, #Appuserrangecolor, #BackendInput, #AppInput {
  --background: rgb(96,125,139,0.33);
  --slider: rgb(17, 166, 7);
  background: var(--background);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
}

.grid-item {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #222;
  border: 7px solid rgba(96,125,139,0.33);
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.target { 
  display: none; 
}
/* Base styling*/
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Popover styling */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.popover__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgb(73, 228, 68);

}

.popover__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.popover__content {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  width: auto;
}
.popover__content:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  right: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: -8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f8f8f8 transparent;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.popover__wrapper:hover .popover__content {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.02, 0.2, 0.97);
}
.popover__message {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="./app.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container" >
      <div style="width: 270px"class="grid-item">
        <header>Preiskalkulator</header>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          App-Benutzer: <br>
          <input id="Appuserrangecolor" value="0" type="range" rangecolorid="Appuserrangecolor" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateUser(this.value, 'Appuserrangecolor');" class='appuser updatecolor'></input>
          <input class='updatecolor' style="width: 30px;border-color: var(--form_border_color);" type="text" id="AppInput" value="0" placeholder="1-100" rangecolorid="Appuserrangecolor" min="0" max="100" oninput="this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value); updateUser(this.value, 'AppInput');"><br>
          Bürosoftware-Benutzer: <br>
          <input id="Backendrangecolor" value="1" type="range" rangecolorid="Backendrangecolor" min="1" max="15" oninput="updateUser(this.value, 'Backendrangecolor'); " class='backenduser updatecolor'></input>
          <input class='updatecolor' style="width: 30px;border-color: var(--form_border_color);" type="text" id="BackendInput" rangecolorid="Backendrangecolor" value="1" min="1" max="15" placeholder="1-15" oninput="this.value = this.value > 15 ? 15 : Math.abs(this.value,); updateUser(this.value, 'BackendInput');"><br>
        </div>
        <b > Bürosoftware wählen </b>
        <select style="width: 150px;background-color:rgba(96,125,139,0.33)" id = "backendfunktion" onchange = "calcSum()" >
          <option value="Z">Zeiterfassung</option>
          <option value="ZR"> Zeiterfassung + Rechnungswesen</option>
        </select>
        <select style="width: 150px;background-color:rgba(96,125,139,0.33)" id = "zahlrythmus" onchange = "calcSum();checkHide(this)" >
          <option onclick="('hidden')" value="J">Jährlich</option>
          <option value="M">monatlich</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="width: 270px">
        <table style="width:100%;text-align: right;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 138px" >App-Benutzer<br > <div class='text-grey'>pro <span class="proapp" >7.50</span>€</div></td>
            <td style="width: 62px; vertical-align: top;" class='appanzahl'>0.00€</td>
          </tr>
          <div class="popover__wrapper">
              <div class="popover__title" style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;text-align: left;">Info</div>
            <div class="popover__content">
              <p class="popover__message">Preisstaffelung</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <tr>
            <td>Bürosoftware-Benutzer<br ><div class='text-grey'>pro <span class='probackend'>20.00</span>€</div></td>
            <td class='backendpreissum' style="vertical-align: top;">20.00€</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td >Gesamtpreis mtl.:<br><div class='text-grey'>(zzgl. MwSt)</div></td>
            <td class='summe' style="vertical-align: top;">20.00€</td>
          </tr>
          <table id="hiddenMonthly" style="width:100%;text-align: right;">
            <tr>
              <td>Jährlich<br></td>
              <td class='jaehrlichsum' >240.00€</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td  class='text-grey'>Rabatt<br></td>
              <td class='rabattsum'>0.00€</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know close to little about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: I hope you’ll find your answer here soon. By then, I’d like to recommend rethinking your interaction design. Hover only works with a pointing device like a mouse. People also use touch screens, keyboards and other devices to navigate apps and websites. Also, interacting with complex content like a table is very tricky when opened only by hover. You should consider opening a dialog to show that table.

Comment: @andy what is a dialog in this case?

Comment: Synonyms are popup or modal. Like a window that stays visible until you close it. See [the `<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

Answer (score 0):

first make table disappear from the page by adding display none to it, how i understood its the grid-container which is the table you want to show on hower
so then just simply create class .show or something like inside css that which would contain,then take out from the DOM the both table and info elements
`display:block`,after `addeventlistener` to info element
`info.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {table.classList.toggle(show)})`